# Reading repeated information from the file in different order in Python

Tags: python, readfile

I tried to search for similar questions, but I couldn't find. Please mark as a duplicate if there is similar questions available.

I'm trying to figure out a way to read and gather multiple information from single file. Here in the file Block-A,B & C are repeated in random order and Block-C has more than one information to capture. Every block end with 'END' text. Here is the input file:

```
Block-A:
(info1)
END
Block-B:
(info2)
END
Block-C:
(info3)
(info4)
END

Block-C:
(info7)
(info8)
END
Block-A:
(info5)
END
Block-B:
(info6)
END
```

Here is my code:

```
import re
out1 = out2 = out3 = ""
a = b = c = False
array=[]

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Block-A'):
            line = next(f)
            out1 = line
            a = True
        if line.startswith('Block-B'):
            line=next(f)
            out2 = line
            b = True
        if line.startswith('Block-C'):
            c = True

        if c:
            line=next(f)
            if not line.startswith('END\n'):
                out3 = line
                array.append(out3.strip())

        if a == b == c == True:
            print(out1.rstrip() +', ' + out2.rstrip() + ', ' + str(array))
            a = b = c = False
            array=[]
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary for the datas from each block. When you read the line that starts a block, set a variable to that name, and use it as the key into the dictionary.

```
out = {}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.endswidth(':'):
            blockname = line[:-1]
            if not blockname in out:
                out[blockname] = ''
        elif line == 'END'
            blockname = None
        else if blockname:
            out[blockname] += line
print(out)
```

Comment: it works great. Very efficient. Is there any way to print the results after reading Block-A,B&C every time?

Comment: You could print it in the `if line == 'End':` code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the Block-X to print, unhash the elif statment

```
import os
data = r'/home/x/Desktop/test'

txt = open(data, 'r')

for line in txt.readlines():
    line = line[:-1]
    if line in ('END'):
        pass
    #elif line.startswith('Block'):
       # pass
    else:
        print line
>>>>
Block-A:
(info1)
Block-B:
(info2)
Block-C:
(info3)
(info4)
Block-C:
(info7)
(info8)
Block-A:
(info5)
Block-B:
(info6)
```

Comment: I'm looking to print the print the Block-A,B,C info's every time, all 3 block are read.

Comment: Are you looking for a print out line by line?

Comment: In everyline, each A,B & C info

A: (info1)  B: (info2) C: (info3) (info4)
A: (info5)  B: (info6) C: (info7) (info8)